# Created two action bars on the same screen - one at top and one at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to develop an android application, and I want to add two action bars one top of the screen and the second on the bottom of the screen. I created the first action bar and it is set on top of the screen but when I try to create the second action bar, this is also created on top of the screen. I set in Mainfest android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow", but the second action bar is set on top of the screen.
Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    View fragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.container);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Tab alleTab = actionBar.newTab();
    alleListTabListener = new TabListener<AlleFragment>(this, R.id.container, AlleFragment.class);
    alleTab.setText("Alle").setContentDescription("Alle page").setTabListener(alleListTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(alleTab);

    Tab favoriteTab = actionBar.newTab();
    favoriteListTabListener = new TabListener<FavoriteFragment>(this, R.id.container, FavoriteFragment.class);
    favoriteTab.setText("Favorite").setContentDescription("Favorite page").setTabListener(favoriteListTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(favoriteTab);

    Tab umbegungTab = actionBar.newTab();
    umbegunfListTabListener = new TabListener<UmbegungFragment>(this, R.id.container, UmbegungFragment.class);
    umbegungTab.setText("Umbegung").setContentDescription("Umbegung page").setTabListener(umbegunfListTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(umbegungTab);

    ActionBar bottomActionBar = getActionBar();
    bottomActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab shoutsTab = bottomActionBar.newTab();
    shoutsTab.setCustomView(R.layout.shouts_item_menuview).setContentDescription("Shouts page").setTabListener(umbegunfListTabListener);
    bottomActionBar.addTab(shoutsTab);


}
```

Can someoane tell me how to put the second action bar at the bottom?

**UPDATE**
[image: +]

I want to have the first part of the menu witch includes Favorite and Umbegung at the top and the last part witch has the word Shouts and exclamation mark at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You may wish to post a screenshot showing what you are getting. Note that the action bar tabs will show on a dedicated "bar" on phones in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

First, tabs at the bottom violate [the Android design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html).

Second, action bar tabs cannot go at the bottom. They will appear where the framework wants them, and on a phone in portrait, they will go in a full-width row beneath the main portion of the action bar.